# HQL query with LIKE having issues

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am working on a search query using HQL and everything works find until I get to the LIKE clause. No matter what I do it does not seem to execute the LIKE clause properly. Here is my query.

```
String QUERY = "FROM Person as p WHERE p.createUser = : createUser 
     AND p.personId in (SELECT pn.personId FROM PersonName pn WHERE pn.personNameType = 'FIRST' AND pn.name LIKE '%:firstName%')";

(List<Person>)session.createQuery(QUERY).setString("createUser", createUser).setString("firstName", firstName).list();
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Parameters inside string literals are not resolved.

You need to add `%`s to parameter values with string concatenation - either at the program side

```
String QUERY = "FROM Person as p WHERE p.createUser = : createUser 
     AND p.personId in " +
     "(SELECT pn.personId FROM PersonName pn " + 
     "WHERE pn.personNameType = 'FIRST' " + 
     "AND pn.name LIKE :firstName)";

(List<Person>)session.createQuery(QUERY)
    .setString("createUser", createUser)
    .setString("firstName", "%" + firstName + "%").list();
```

or at the database side:

```
String QUERY = "FROM Person as p WHERE p.createUser = : createUser 
     AND p.personId in " +
     "(SELECT pn.personId FROM PersonName pn " + 
     "WHERE pn.personNameType = 'FIRST' " + 
     "AND pn.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :firstName, '%'))";

(List<Person>)session.createQuery(QUERY)
    .setString("createUser", createUser)
    .setString("firstName", firstName).list();
```

Comment: What about case sensitivity. Is there a way to make it case insensitive? Thanks for the reply! @axtavt

Comment: cast `pn.name` and the parameter `firstName` to lower case in your query

Answer (score 4):

we can use multiple concat to resolve this issue.

```
SELECT pn.personId FROM PersonName pn WHERE pn.personNameType = 'FIRST' AND pn.name LIKE concat(concat('%', :firstName), '%')
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I use `AND pn.name LIKE '%' || :firstName || '%'` for the shorter way.